# lmer providing p values by specific levels within a variable

Tags: r, regression, lme4

I am having issues with a regression analysis I'm attempting to run. I want to examine the correlation between a specific receptor density within a brain region and the functional connectivity of that region with another region in the brain. Plus I have added in the variables of age and dose of nicotine into my model. But when I run the regression, the output includes statistics for specific levels of the variables in question, rather than just an effect for the whole variable. Also, weirdly, only specific levels have statistics provided rather than all levels. For instance it will give me a p-value for my low nicotine rats and saline rats but not for the high nicotine group. Any ideas what's happening?

Here's a piece of my data frame:

```
Rat Age.x  Dose  Mean_1  Log_Avg
6   Adult  LN  -0.0053   0.0244
10  Adol   HN   0.01061  0.0617
7   Adol   Sal -0.0318   0.0428
21  Adult  HN   0.0392   0.0600
```

This is my model for my regression:

```
Po_Regression<-lmer(Mean_1 ~ Log_Avg + Dose + Age.x + Dose*Age.x + (1|Rat), data = Po_Graph, control=lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nlev = "ignore",check.nobs.vs.rankZ = "ignore",check.nobs.vs.nRE="ignore"))
```

I get this output from it:

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method [lmerModLmerTest]
Formula: Mean_1 ~ Log_Avg + Dose + Age.x + Dose * Age.x + (1 | Rat)
   Data: Po_Graph
Control: 
lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nlev = "ignore", check.nobs.vs.rankZ = "ignore",  
    check.nobs.vs.nRE = "ignore")

REML criterion at convergence: -137.9

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.26769 -0.70154  0.00813  0.57583  2.85011 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance  Std.Dev.
 Rat      (Intercept) 0.0002083 0.01443 
 Residual             0.0037911 0.06157 
Number of obs: 62, groups:  Rat, 62

Fixed effects:
                    Estimate Std. Error        df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)         0.098727   0.046705 55.000000   2.114 0.039077 *  
Log_Avg            -0.129351   0.525355 55.000000  -0.246 0.806431    
DoseLN             -0.005547   0.029423 55.000000  -0.189 0.851154    
DoseSal            -0.115904   0.035418 55.000000  -3.272 0.001845 ** 
Age.xAdult         -0.056001   0.029425 55.000000  -1.903 0.062257 .  
DoseLN:Age.xAdult   0.002563   0.039653 55.000000   0.065 0.948698    
DoseSal:Age.xAdult  0.144597   0.041160 55.000000   3.513 0.000894 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) Lg_Avg DoseLN DoseSl Ag.xAd DLN:A.
Log_Avg     -0.904                                   
DoseLN      -0.433  0.157                            
DoseSal     -0.758  0.572  0.474                     
Age.xAdult  -0.602  0.344  0.516  0.580              
DsLN:Ag.xAd  0.194  0.024 -0.720 -0.271 -0.646       
DsSl:Ag.xAd  0.480 -0.301 -0.377 -0.751 -0.734  0.461
```

I included the lmercontrol bit because without it I kept getting this error message:
"Error: number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations"

The lmercontrol bit stopped that error from occurring but if I'm honest I'm not 100% sure what exactly it's doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its important to keep in mind what each term mean. If you have a continous predictor then the intercept is what that predicted outcome is, when that variable is set to zero.

If you have a factor predictor, such as your dose variable, then it uses one factor as the baserate which is the intercept. Each factor term in your model is how much change you would expect by changing from one factor to another.

Good luck!